# OO Javascript and this keyword. Object Literals

Tags: javascript

I'm having issues with Javascript properties and "this" keyword. Forgive me here for asking my third and final JS OOP question. OOP in Javascript has been a headache for me today.

I'm trying to set the property 'source' but the error console is saying it's undefined in parseSource method.

After a little research I believe this.source is is referring to window.source? The code is a boilerplate from Mozilla. When creating extensions init is called by FireFox when the plugin is initialized.

What's the best way to go about setting the properties when creating objects using literal notation?

```
var myExtension = {
source: null,

init: function() {  
    // The event can be DOMContentLoaded, pageshow, pagehide, load or unload.  
    if(gBrowser) {
        gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", this.onPageLoad, false);  
    }
},  

onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {  
    doc = aEvent.originalTarget; // doc is document that triggered the event  
    win = doc.defaultView; // win is the window for the doc  

    // Skip frames and iFrames
    if (win.frameElement) return;

    this.source = win.document.getElementById('facebook').innerHTML;
    myExtension.parseSource();
},

parseSource: function() {
    if(this.source == null) {
        // So something
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }
}
}  

window.addEventListener("load", function() { myExtension.init(); }, false);
```

Comment: BTW, this isn't really about OOP in JavaScript so much as function invocation and `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a callback function to `gBrowser.addEventListener` like this:

```
gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", this.onPageLoad, false);
```

you are passing a reference to the function which is essentially "detached" from the `this` object where it is defined. So, you need to do something like the following in order to correctly maintain what `this` references:

```
init: function() {  
    var self = this;
    if(gBrowser) {
        gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            self.onPageLoad();
        }, false);  
    }
},
```

In newer browsers (you did say this is a FF extension), you can use [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to the same effect:

```
init: function() {
    if(gBrowser) {
        gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", this.onPageLoad.bind(this), false);  
    }
},
```

---

Once that's cleared up, you can change the `onPageLoad` function to:

```
onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {  
    doc = aEvent.originalTarget; // doc is document that triggered the event  
    win = doc.defaultView; // win is the window for the doc  

    // Skip frames and iFrames
    if (win.frameElement) return;

    this.source = win.document.getElementById('facebook').innerHTML;
    this.parseSource();
},
```

---

#### Edit

A stripped-down demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/bDe6N/

Comment: But changing the this.pageSource() is going to cause the same issue I had in my previous question about the method not being defined. This is so much of a headache I am tempted to just use functions for this. I've learned OOP and graduated university with a 1:1 in software engineering, yet this is just mind numbing.

Comment: this.source is still undefined in the pageSource function though. Even after following your advice above.

Comment: Ignore my last post. It works, I actually understand why it failed now. Thank you again Matt.

Comment: You're welcome. I actually just edited my post to show you the basic idea in action `:)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that methods in Javacript forget about their `this` if you pass them as a parameter. They only work if you pass them looking like a method

```
//this doesn't work in JS
f = obj.method
f()
//wtf man! You have to call it looking like a method
obj.method()
```

In your case this happens because you pass this.onPageLoad as a parameter. Function parameters act like the variable from the last example.

The workaround is to use a wrapper function in order to preserve the method-call appearance

```
addEventListener( ..., function(){ return this.onPageLoad(); }, ...)
```

except that `this` is not lexicaly scoped and the inner function gets a wrong copy as well. After another quick fix we obtain

```
var that = this;
addEventListener(..., function(){ that.onPageLoad(); }, ...);
```

This should do the job now.